# Program won't accept $2(-5x+1)(-4x+3)$ as an answer to factoring $40x^2-38x+6$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Here is what I have done so far:

$2(20x^2-19x+3)$ //factored the GCF

$60x² $//Multiplied $3$ into $20x²$

$-15x -4x$ //These two numbers add into $-19x$, and multiply into $60x²$

$2((20x^2-15x)(-4x+3))$ //Put it into form again.

$2(-5x(-4x+3)1(-4x+3))$ //Factored the GCF out of each grouping.

$2(-5x+1)(-4x+3)$ //Reformatted to try and get the final answer.

I am stuck on this step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a high school math student, so I am obviously not an expert in this stuff. I just want to understand what I did wrong or what the computer wants and learn from it.

Comment: Which program/software are we talking about?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  It's a problem with the program.  Try multiplying each of the last two factors by $-1$ and see if it will accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation seems fine, you could try to insert as answer the equivalent

$$40x^2-38x+6=2(5x-1)(4x-3)$$

by a simple change in sign for the two factors.

Comment: Thank you. This and Saulspatz's recommendation worked. I can't accept an answer until 9 minutes from now though.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye